# Чем качественно отличаются ashmem и pmem в Android?

Tags: android

Чем качественно отличаются ashmem и pmem в Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anonymous SHared MEMory (ASHMEM) изпользует виртуальную память, а Physical MEMory (PMEM) использует физическую память. Обычно PMEM используется тогда, когда нужна значительная неразрывная физическая область памяти.